Data Validation error - Mismatched Records
We are doing PostgreSQL to Aurora PostgreSQL data migration using AWS DMS.
We are seeing the mismatched records error during the validation.
We are seeing some extra space at source.
[[{'user': 'xxxxx   '}, {'user': 'xxxxx'}],]
How we can write an override function in validation rules or any other way to overcome this.
I tried below
"rule-type": "validation",
"rule-id": "5",
"rule-name": "5",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "public",
"table-name": "%",
"column-name": "user"
},
"rule-action": "override-validation-function",
"source-function": "rtrim(${column-name})"
},

Just curious why you would use the data validation option. It basically performs a mock full load. Can you turn that off and see if any errors are more verbose?
